# How does one manage the upload speed of Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I love file-sharing platforms like Ubuntu One. Up to now I used Dropbox and there you can see the progress of uploading (with moving the mouse-cursor over the Dropbox icon on the lower right edge).

In Ubuntu One I don't see a way to control the progress of uploading. I really miss that function, because it seems to synchronise quite slow (a 22 MB file is syncing for several minutes now).

Is there a way to control the progress?

Comment: Are you looking for a progress bar or for an indicator that shows what Ubuntu One is doing?

Comment: Both would be helpful. I don't see a progress bar at my screen and i didn't know what U1 was doing until i installed the packed decribed by giowck (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ubuntu one indicator, but I never tested it: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, that's great help. Now i have a little cloud at the top bar and it shows me most of the wanted information.

Comment: @Roland Taylor, yes you're right, next time I will include a full answer.

Comment: @giowck: btw I use this indicator too on both my laptops :D

Answer (score 2):

In the Ubuntu One settings application there is an option to allow setting the maximum upload and download bandwidth used.  Look under the "Devices" tab in the Ubuntu One application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that hint. But i have that box checked and no progress bar is visible. Now i have and indicator at the top (see that hint below), that's helping me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One client shows a progress bar and when it's running, you can see a progressbar on the clients launcher as well.

Comment: A progress bar would help me a lot. But i don't see one. Am i blind or do i do something wrong??? Please look to this screenshot: http://ubuntuone.com/6RXlpZgiCnebxEpFK9nh77
Where is a progress bar that shows me what part of the file "9. 11. 1918 ..." i actually been loaded up?

Comment: Perhaps I remembered wrong. Seing the screenshot from fader, it may have been that progressbar I thought about. Sorry. But if you run the client and look at the Launcher on the left side of the screen, does it have a progressbar?

Comment: No, i never have seen any progressbar with U1. Should there be any or was it in older versions?