# Why does my Ubuntu One upload rate vary so much over a cellular connection?

Tags: ubuntu-one

My "problem" is that Ubuntu One upload rate goes from 30 kbps to 15, then to 8 and 4 kbps, then again goes to 30, 15, 8, 4 kbps... what's wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS AMD64, connected to the Internet through an Android Wi-Fi hotspot.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you describe sounds like your upload is being throttled, but not smoothly, which is why you see these bursts followed by very slow speeds.

> *connected to the Internet through an Android Wi-Fi hotspot.*

- If you are using your *mobile connection* (via a "hotspot" created on your Android device), then note that cellular upload speeds are often much lower than download speeds.
- Your cellular provider may deliberately be throttling your data upload speeds.
- Your speed may also be affected by the extra "hop" -- between your computer and the Android device.
- On your/Ubuntu One's side, all you can do is check that you have not [set Ubuntu One to itself limit upload speed](https://askubuntu.com/a/92258/58612):

[image]

Comment: This may also be partly due to varying signal strength on the cellular network.  If you have exceptionally strong signal strength, you will get smooth connectivity, if you get widely-varying signal strength (high -> low -> medium -> low -> none -> low ...), it'll increase and decrease your connectivity crazily (and when you see 'none', well, you can guess what's there :P)